# MassTransit: how to send a message to specific consumers?

Tags: message-queue, masstransit

Sorry if my question is dumb, I'm new to MassTransit.

My system consists of a server and multiple client devices.
I'd like to send a message from the server to a specific client or to a group of clients.
As far as I understand, `IBusControl.Publish` sends the message to all subscribers, and `IBusControl.Send` to the only one subscriber.

How can I achieve this using MassTransit?
My transports are RabbitMQ / Azure Service Bus.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MassTransit implements standard messaging patterns, which aren't MassTransit-specific. Point-to-point, publish-subscribe, invalid message channel, dead letter channel and so on:

[image]

You indeed have the choice between sending a message to one consumer using `Send` and to broadcast messages to all subscribers for that message type by using `Publish`.

Everything else can be easily done by adding code to consumers:

```
await bus.Publish(new MyMessage { ReceiverGroup = "group1", ... });
```

and

```
public async Task Consume(IContext<MyMessage> context)
{
    if (context.Message.ReceiverGroup != myGroup) return;

    ...
}
```